# change class of glyphicon when nav-item is open

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap menu on a web page.

my menu list looks something like this:

```
       <li><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" 
       role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
       expanded="false">main item

        <span class="pull-left glyph-btn-menu">
       <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></em>
       </span>
       </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        sub item1<br>
        sub item2<br>
        sub item2<br>
        </div>
        </li>
```

I want glyphicon symbol to change to class glyphicon-menu-up when nav-link is clicked and submenu items open and then again to change back to glyphicon-menu-down when nav-item is closed or when a different nav-item is clicked.

What would be the best way to acheive that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is my solution.

I gave the parent ul the an id value:  id="theme"

bootstrap adds the class open to an open li so I check to see if any li have the class open, remove and add glyphicon classes as needed

```
        $('#theme li').click(function () {
          if($(this).hasClass('open')){
              //alert('aaa');
                $(this).children('a').children('span').children('em').removeClass('glyphicon-menu-up');
              $(this).children('a').children('span').children('em').addClass('glyphicon-menu-down');
              } else {
                $(this).children('a').children('span').children('em').removeClass('glyphicon-menu-down');
              $(this).children('a').children('span').children('em').addClass('glyphicon-menu-up');
                  }
        });
```